# Convert a PreBuildEvent to a Target with a Condition?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a project called `cryptdll.vcxproj`. *cryptdll* depends on artifacts from two other projects in the solution. The other projects are *cryptlib* and *cryptest*. For those interested in the layout of elements in *cryptdll*, it is located at [`cryptdll`](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptdll.vcxproj).

The dependencies are somewhat unusual and not easily expressed in the Visual Studio editor. They are unusual because policy requires `Win32\Output\Debug\cryptest.exe` always be used to perform a `PostBuildEvent` *cryptdll*.

I found I could add the following to *cryptdll* to get things working as expected:

```xml
<!-- Win32/Debug cryptest.exe for DLL MAC'ing -->
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="!Exists('Win32\Output\Debug\cryptest.exe')" Label="MAC tool">
  <PreBuildEvent>
    <Message>Creating Win32/Debug cryptest.exe for MAC computation</Message>
    <Command>
      msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=Win32 cryptlib.vcxproj
      msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=Win32 cryptest.vcxproj
    </Command>
  </PreBuildEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

When I attempted to convert it to a Target it stopped working. Below is the target rule.

```xml
<!-- Win32/Debug cryptest.exe for DLL MAC'ing -->
<Target Condition="!Exists('Win32\Output\Debug\cryptest.exe')" Name="MAC tool" Label="MAC tool">
  <MSbuild
    Projects="cryptlib.vcxproj"
    Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=Win32;"/>
  <MSbuild
    Projects="cryptest.vcxproj"
    Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=Win32;"/>
</Target>
```

My question is, what is wrong with the code converted to a Target, and how do I fix it?

---

For completeness, I want what the Makefile folks call a ***[Prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)***. The best I can tell from searching, every result for ["MSBuild prerequisite"](https://www.google.com/search?q=MSBuild+prerequisite) is irrelevant.

---

Here is what the Target'd output looks like. Notice the task is skipped as if it did not exist.

```
>del /q /s Win32 x64
...

>msbuild /t:build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 cryptdll.vcxproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.1055.0

Build started 10/6/2016 11:40:26 AM.
Project "c:\cryptopp\cryptdll.vcxproj" on node 1 (build target(s)).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "x64\cryptdll\Release\".
  Creating directory "x64\DLL_Output\Release\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\cryptdll\Release\cryptdll.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCre
  ate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  Performing Custom Build Tools
   Assembling: c:\cryptopp\x64dll.asm
ClCompile:
  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\AMD64\CL.exe /c /Z
  i /nologo /W4 /WX- /O2 /Ob2 /Oi /Oy /D NDEBUG /D CRYPTOPP_EXPORTS /D CRYPTOPP
  _ENABLE_COMPLIANCE_WITH_FIPS_140_2=1 /D USE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS /D _WINDLL /G
  F /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yc"pch.h" /Fp"
  x64\cryptdll\Release\cryptopp.pch" /Fo"x64\cryptdll\Release\\" /Fd"x64\cryptd
  ll\Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:none pch.cpp
  pch.cpp
  ...

  <rest of the DLL is built>

PostBuildEvent:
  Description: Adding MAC to DLL

          Win32\output\debug\cryptest.exe mac_dll "cryptopp\x64\DLL_Output\Rele
  ase\cryptopp.dll"
          IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo mac done > "x64\DLL_Output\Release\"\cryp
  topp.mac.done)

  :VCEnd
  The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
13,5): error MSB3073: The command "\r [c:\cryptopp\cryptdll.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
13,5): error MSB3073:         Win32\output\debug\cryptest.exe mac_dll "c:\crypt
opp\x64\DLL_Output\Release\cryptopp.dll"\r [c:\cryptopp\cryptdll.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
13,5): error MSB3073:         IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (echo mac done > "x64\DLL_O
utput\Release\"\cryptopp.mac.done)\r [c:\cryptopp\cryptdll.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
13,5): error MSB3073:       \r [c:\cryptopp\cryptdll.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
13,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 3. [c:\cryptopp\cryptdll.vcxproj
Done Building Project "c:\cryptopp\cryptdll.vcxproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILE
D.

Build FAILED.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When I attempted to convert it to a Task* You mean a [`Target`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx), that is not the same as a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77f2hx1s.aspx): the first contains the latter.

*Notice the task is skipped as if it did not exist.* Well you don't tell msbuild anywhere what to do with the target so it cannot possibly know when to invoke it. You want it called before the build so you must express that somehow. Here, the BeforeTargets attribute (documentation in same link above) is the canonical way:

```
<Target Condition="!Exists('Win32\Output\Debug\cryptest.exe')"
        Name="MAC tool"
        BeforeTargets="Build">
```

sidenote: why bother adding a Label to a target which just duplicates the name?

Comment: Thanks @stijn. Let me ask a dumb question until my copy of [MSBuild Trickery: 99 Ways to Bend the Build Engine to Your Will](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/061550907X) arrives. How do I express what a Makefile would call a ***prerequisite***? That's what want to do. For completeness, here's GNU Make's manual page on prerequisites: [4.3 Types of Prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html). If you want a laugh, try searching for [MSBuild prerequisite](https://www.google.com/search?q=MSBuild+prerequisite) and look at all the irrelevant results.

Comment: Thanks again @stijn. I tried removing the duplicate *`Name`* attribute. It results in ***`The required attribute "Name" is empty or missing from the element <Target>.`***. I also tried the most obvious name, but it results in an error too: *`Name="cryptest.exe"`*. If you are wondering why *`Label`* is there, the MSBuild docs told me they are like *"display names"* for tools like IDEs, so they must always be present. If they are not present, then we risk user questions and bug reports.

Comment: A prerequisite would be expressed using the DependsOnTargets attribute. Regarding the duplication: Name is the required attribute, not Label. I dont know what docs you are referring to, but if there already is a hard requirement for a Label somewhere it won't be for Target elements since it's labels are afaik never dislayed in a gui anywhere, especially not for custom elements not added by the ui in the first place, that's only the case for some Property/Item/ImportGroups.

Comment: Regarding *" [Labels] ... I dont know what docs you are referring to"*, see [A guide to .vcxproj and .props file structure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure/). Let me get back to you on the other part about prerequisites. I'm getting ready to test it.

Comment: Thanks again @stijn. I *think* you answered the question. The problem was, I asked the wrong question. You should not be penalized for my ignorance or Microsoft docs. You get the points.

Comment: Note that is not official documentation. But it seems legit and correct and e.g. first mention about labels is: *Labels are arbitrary tags only read and written by Visual Studio and used as signposts for editing; they have no other function*