# MSBuild does not honor prerequisite specified via DependsOnTargets

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, target, prerequisites

I'm having trouble getting a prerequisite built. [The regular *Make* program calls them prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html), but MSBuild calls them *Targets* with *DependsOnTargets*.

Would someone please ***clearly*** state how to make an artifact from one C++ project a prerequisite of another [current] C++ project. Please be sure to state where to place it among all the parts of a C++ project file. If needed, here are the parts of a project file: [A guide to .vcxproj and .props file structure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/05/14/a-guide-to-vcxproj-and-props-file-structure/).

This question is very similar to [Convert a PreBuildEvent to a Target with a Condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39900437/) I asked the wrong question, which caused the resulting answer to not work. Fortunately, @stijn was able to tell me what Microsoft calls a prerequisite.

---

For those who are interested, here's about as far as I have gotten with it. Everything I try results in MSBuild silently skipping the prerequisite. Building with `/verbosity:detailed` or `/verbosity:diagnostic` does not even mention the name *MAC tool*. I place it just before `ItemGroup` where the source files are placed.

```
<!-- Win32/Debug cryptest.exe for DLL MAC'ing -->
<!-- Broken at the moment; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39900437 -->
<Target
  Condition="!Exists('Win32\Output\Debug\cryptest.exe')"
  Name="MAC Tool"
  Label="MAC tool"
  DependsOnTargets="Projects=cryptest.vcxproj;Configuration=Debug;Platform=Win32;" >
  <Message
    Text="Creating Win32/Debug cryptest.exe for MAC computation" />
</Target>
```

In the code above, the current project is `cryptdll.vcxproj`. The external project dependency is `cryptest.vcxproj`. Users are supposed to `msbuild cryptdll.vcxproj /t:Build ...`. If the external dpendency (`cryptest.exe`) is missing, then it will be built with no action on the part of a user. Things are supposed to "just work" for them.

---

For those who would like a laugh, here's Microsoft's documentation on `DependsOnTargets`. First, [Target Element (MSBuild)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx):

> The targets that must be executed before this target can be executed
>   or top-level dependency analysis can occur. Multiple targets are
>   separated by semicolons.

Then a little further down the page:

> The MSBuild engine executes dependencies in the order in which they
>   appear in the DependsOnTargets attribute, from left to right. For more
>   information, see [MSBuild Targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx).

Second, following the link for [MSBuild Targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx) which is supposed to discuss it further:

> 

That's right, there is no mention of `DependsOnTargets`.

---

Here is the full output of `msbuild /verbosity:detailed`: [Pastebin MSBuild](http://pastebin.com/YQh5aaC7). It was placed on Pastebin because its too big for Stack Overflow.

There is no mention of *"MAC tool"*. It appears MSBuild is silently skipping it even though its supposed to be evaluated everytime.

Comment: For anyone who can *clearly* and *concisely* answer the question such that it "just works" for me, I'll peel off 250 points and award you a Bounty. I wasted over one man-week on three simple tasks under MSBuild. I'm tried of wasting time on it and in the incomplete and missing documentation. I'm happy to provide the points so I move on to the next tasks.

Comment: *The targets that must be executed before this target can be executed* it says *targets*, whereas you enter a semicolon-sepearted list of what looks like property delcarations, that won't work, you need to enter a Target there which is known in the project's scope.

Comment: *there is no mention of DependsOnTargets* it mentions 'target dependencies' which is what DependsOnTargets expresses and says 'see Target Build Order for details' which does list DependsOnTargets among others. Ah, the documentation mazes.

Comment: Anyway, the principle you used in the previous question ('before the build of this project, build another project if it's output is not yet there') imo perfectly expresses that the other project is a prerequisite of this one, why not just stick with it? Maybe you should not stare yourself blind on comparing make with msbuild since their core principles are rather different. make has like one canonical way to do this, msbuild seems to have multiple (and as you figured, also with different naming)

Comment: Another solution, pun intended, is to express dependencies/build order at the solution level and build the solution instead of building seperate projects.

Comment: Thnaks @stijn. Let's handle first things first. Why is `Target` not being evaluated? My thinking is, even if `DependsOnTargets` is completely broken, I should still see an entry for the `Target` with `/verbosity:detailed`. For completeness, I tried to change `Name` to `"*"` so it would match everything, but that did not work. It resulted in an illegal character error.

Comment: I think only targets which, after evaluation of the dependencies, might be considered for execution are logged (there are hundreds of targets in a project and all it's imports and they are not all logged). *I tried to change Name to "*" so it would match everything* names aren't matched, they are treated literally

Comment: Thanks again @stijn - At this point I've run out of time to work the problem. The 250 point offer stands for anyone who has time for it. In the meantime, we've told people to [avoid MSBuild for ARM because its unsupported](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/MSBuild_(Command_Line)#ARM_Platforms). We pushed it back on Microsoft: *"At this point, until Microsoft releases documentation on the procedure, we are calling ARM-based MSBuilds completely broken"*.

Comment: *work the problem* but is there a problem left? As said, DependsOnTargets doesn't help you here since you want to express a project dependency and certain build order. Your current solution with BeforeTargets works perfectly, no? And otherwsie your repository also seems to have has a .sln with likely the dependencies setup so that's perfectly usable as well?